# How do I compute this limit? $\lim_{x \to \infty} (k_1\log x -k_2x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I found this limit as a last step of another problem, so there isn't much to explain. I get $\infty -\infty$ but i don't know how to tackle it, Any ideas?

Let $k_1, k_2>0, \lim_{x \to \infty} (k_1\log x -k_2x)$

This is how Wolfram tackles it, but I am unfamiliar with that property. If someone could do it without it, and explain or point to a proof of  this property it would be great
[image]

Comment: $\log x$ is dwarfed by $x$, so the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts you mean $\log x =o(x)  $ as $ x \to  \infty$?

Comment: It's $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x} = 0$$
hence $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(k_1\frac{\log x}{x}-k_2\right)=-k_2$$
hence when you multiply the target of lim with $x$ then...